# How to use socket.io in mean.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, mean.io

I am just a newbie in MEAN development and I am using latest version of [mean.io](http://mean.io/). I want to use socket.io so that when any thing happens with the post I should not make any reload to check those changes. I have gone through mean.io docs and the documentation is not good at all. So can someone tell me how to use socket.io here? Any help or suggestion will be really appreciable.

Comment: Have you checked out the Socket.IO documentation?  Its really straight forward. 

https://socket.io/docs/

Comment: Yes I have checked the documentation. But I am not getting how to use that in mean.io